# how to Sort sheet for importhtml via google sheet, was using Query not solved

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

hi how to sort the google sheet with row running number was been added automatic by us as automatic by importhtml sync + then sort descending row number Z - A, A - Z OR 10 - 1 , 1 - 10 in a row?

but the table name [ No, VERSION,   SOURCE, RELEASE DATE,   IS BETA ] - are not be sort in first row.. only sort second row : eg (B2),(C2),(D2),(E2)...

here the code i was used :

```
=QUERY(
  IMPORTHTML(
   "https:// wabetainfo.com/updates/",
   "table",2),
  "select * offset 0",1)
```

i mean for this : can make;

if i use this direct code direct

```
IMPORTHTML("https:// wabetainfo.com/updates/", "table",2)
```

the data second column are the latest one update - mean September 2 ....

and now i want to make the latest one update that go make descending sort became last one column.

that mean :

last row, column = latest update

second row, column = previous / oldest update..

that all

thanks for helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
=query(
{IMPORTHTML("https://wabetainfo.com/updates/", "table",2),
arrayformula(substitute(query(IMPORTHTML("https://wabetainfo.com/updates/", "table",2),"select Col3"),",","")*1)},
"select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4 where Col1 is not null order by Col5")
```

Comment: that work, for the descending (number row 10 - 1 ) version number but for the other row not valid for that option - mean not same retrieve / fetch data 

like this sample image  : https://ibb.co/gVrVqmK

Comment: if i use this direct code direct 

```
IMPORTHTML("https://wabetainfo.com/updates/", "table",2)
```

the data second column are the latest one update - mean September 2 .... 

and now i want to make the latest one update that go make descending sort became last one column. 

that mean :

last row, column = latest update 
second row, column = previous update..

Comment: want ask can be the date convert to any GMT time or use location Asia/Singapore for the table date and time that ? if Possible  let me know the script or formula. Thanks

Comment: to get time, remove commas `=query(arrayformula(substitute(query(IMPORTHTML("https://wabetainfo.com/updates/", "table",2),"select Col3"),",","")*1))` but we can't transform it to GMT+8 since we don't know the time zone of the source !