# How to Convert time in a import html > For time, date in GMT8+ in Sheet new row (F2)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

i was importhtml to google sheet, so right now i want to convert date and time ( in GMT+8 / or Asia/Singapore ) the data in the new row can

importhtml i was used like this :

```
IMPORTHTML("https:// wabetainfo.com /updates/", "table",2)
```

so now want to convert in new row that time to GMT / "Asia/Singapore" any script or formula to do with that ?

Thanks

Comment: This has already been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69082100/how-to-sort-sheet-for-importhtml-via-google-sheet-was-using-query-not-solved/69082990?noredirect=1#comment122097915_69082990

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to Sort sheet for importhtml via google sheet, was using Query not solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69082100/how-to-sort-sheet-for-importhtml-via-google-sheet-was-using-query-not-solved)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You can create a custom function in Apps Script which converts to the `GMT+8` timezone!

The conversion can be easily done by using your own custom function:

**Custom function**

```
function CONVERTDATE(date) {
  let time = new Date(date);
  let seconds = time.getTime();
  let addHours = 8 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  let hoursLater = new Date(seconds + addHours);
  let converted = Utilities.formatDate(hoursLater,Session.getTimeZone(), "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
  return converted;
}
```

**How to use?**

Assuming that:

- you want your converted values in the `E` column
- `E1` is the header
- `C` is the column which has your dates

You will have to go to your spreadsheet *Tools* > *Script editor* and paste the code above and save it.

Afterwards, you can type in `E2` the following formula `=CONVERTDATE(C2)` and later drag it down across the column.

**Spreadsheet**

Before the formula:

[image: adding the formula]

After the formula:

[image: after the formula]

#### Reference

- [Custom functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions).

Comment: Thanks, for the script - btw the actual date and time in column C2 using UTC time

Comment: btw, that script will be auto added when new data row was been import automatic in sheet ? - eg: data auto added in new row the date will auto convert in the same row E2 - E1000 like that

Comment: if i using the like this formula for auto numbering so change change that to ```=ArrayFormula(if(B3:B<>"",row(A3:A)-2,""))``` -- change to this ```=CONVERTDATE(C2)``` to make that date was auto serial by convertdate

Comment: when i use that scripts the time convert C2 = just fetch same thing not convert actual time in C2 (UTC) and E2 (GMT+8) > here the output : https://ibb.co/jDMb0Tn - and the time became 24hour format, if want to set 12 hour (AM/PM) can ? + want to make that auto complete when the new row auto place the field form htmlimport.

Comment: Just like I have mentioned, you will have to adjust then the "GMT+8" parameter as the new Date ends up taking the spreadsheet's locale as reference.

Comment: sorry i'm lost here.. already change the parameter "GMT+8" still not convert the date form C2 table that still convert like same thing. sorry again

Comment: I have updated the function. Please check if it works now as I simply added 8 hours to the date without using the GMT+8 as reference.

Comment: Thanks new code that totally work thanks. can that script make auto added in the row when new row A was been auto added by importhtml ? thanks again

Comment: I am glad to heat this! Sadly no, you will have to drag down the formula whenever a new row is added.

Comment: i see, ok noted. so that time in convert ```"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"``` can't add for ```HH:mm:ss tt``` for change AM/PM ? thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236955/discussion-between-m-zayn-and-ale13).

Answer (score 0):

Remove comma and apply a format to the column

```
=query(arrayformula(substitute(query(IMPORTHTML("https://wabetainfo.com/updates/", "table",2),"select Col3"),",","")*1))
```

but we can't transform it to GMT+8 since we don't know the time zone of the source !

Comment: hi, thanks. the time form the source is using UTC, if that using UTC still can change ? date + time combine in a row  " The release date is in UTC format "

Comment: btw, was using your code. but the data not descending > need the last row for the latest one date and the first row need enter release date & previous date (oldest data)

Comment: sorry, I don't understand what you need !

Comment: i mean the running that time are not sorting descending ( 10 - 1 ) / ( Z - A ) like before this. For convert that time so no have any script to convert time UTC to GMT+8 ?.. Thanks

Comment: to convert time UTC to GMT+8, you have to add 8 hours, that is `+8/24`